# Does Objective-C have an operator, function, or method that can return -1, 0, or 1 when comparing 2 integers or floats?

Tags: objective-c

I tried to search on Google or Stackoverflow but can't find such an operator.  In C we used to defined a `cmp` macro but is there something built in?

Comment: Objective-C is for objects. When working with integers and floats you should use C syntax. So whatever way you're used to is the right answer.

Comment: Perl or Ruby already has `<=>`... so I wonder if C or Objective-C has something similar... and why not add it for so many years if not already have it...

Comment: Perl and Ruby are scripting languages. Their priorities are completely different. Objective-C is not designed to help you write less code, it's designed to help you write reliable/easy to read code. It doesn't get any easier to understand than an if/else if/else statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Kashiv mentioned, 100% of C is available in Objective-C. However, if you are using the Cocoa Frameworks and are asking about a more "Cocoa" way of doing it, NSNumber has a [compare:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000178-BABDGHEE) method, which returns an [NSComparisonResult](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSComparisonResult), which is either -1, 0 or 1.

However, if we are being thoroughly Cocoa in our programming we should further abstract ourselves from the specific knowledge of -1, 0 and 1 and use the constants NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedSame, and NSOrderedDescending. These are semantically named and that's the real value in programming this way.

```
NSComparisonResult order = [myInt compare:anotherInt];
switch(order) {
  case NSOrderedAscending:
    // myInt is greater than anotherInt
  break;
  // ... etc
}
```

Comment: what if they are not NSNumber?

Comment: Then use any method you would use in C, remembering that in most cases simply subtracting one from the other and checking for less-than-zero, zero, or greater-than-zero is typically sufficient and efficient.

Comment: or I wonder if just returning `a - b` works in most situations.  I was going to use `[@(a) compare: @(b)]` but it may be heavy to convert them into objects, and... does the `@(a)` syntax not exist for some earlier version of Objective-C or Xcode?

Comment: Right, that's very new. And in general, we don't consider it too expensive to convert these to objects. I know it's a tough shift to make mentally; but this is intended to be a purely object-oriented environment; and the folks at NextStep and Apple have built us a very well optimized platform to work with. You won't notice a hit 99.99% of the time.

Comment: Don't use NSNumber unless you have to. Seriously, why do 20,000 CPU instructions when 2 or 3 will get the job done? If you've already got an NSNumber object, then fine. But don't allocate two new ones just so you can see which int is bigger.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert any documentation on that 20k figure? My humble off-the-hip guess would be closer to a few hundred. Further, my attitude toward the decision would hinge primarily on the factor of frequency of execution. Sometimes things like this are in drawing code: do it in C. Sometimes they are one-off when a button is pressed or something: do it OOP and don't mind the cost (design purity trumps when the entire cost is spent before the user even finishes lifting their finger).

Comment: We don't know how many instructions are executed and it is subject to change depending on compiler flags, CPU, and even other things such as how much memory is available and how long ago your app last called that method. One thing is certain, just the memory management alone is drastically slower than a simple int comparison. Memory is being allocated and possibly kept in RAM for several seconds, maybe even swapped to virtual memory. Is it a 16 bit int or a 128 bit float? With NSNumber you do not know. If you have two ints, use C to compare them. If you have two numbers, use NSNumber -compare:

Answer (score 0):

Anything you can do in C, can be done in Objective-C.